# Drop down in Dash Python

Tags: python-3.x, dashboard, plotly-dash

I am building a dash app in python. I want to build an empty drop down which gets populated from a text box.
So, a user enters 'abc' in the text and hits submit. The drop down value gets updated with 'abc'

Can you anyone help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides setting up the components, you just need a single callback that targets the dropdown options as `Output` with the submit button as `Input` and the text value along with the current drop down options as `State`. Here is a small example,

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input, State

app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css'], prevent_initial_callbacks=True)
app.layout = html.Div([dcc.Input(id="input"), html.Button("submit", id="btn"), dcc.Dropdown(id="dd", options=[])])


@app.callback(Output("dd", "options"), [Input("btn", "n_clicks")], [State("input", "value"), State("dd", "options")])
def submit(n_clicks, text, options):
    return options + [{"value": text, "label": text}]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: Great! If your are satisfied with the answer, will you mark the answer as the solution?